# QGIS: Distance Matrix tool omitting some points in output table. (qGIS 2.10.1-Pisa)

Tags: qgis, distance, analysis, distance-matrix

I have used the Analysis Tools -> Distance matrix to merge two datasets by the closest points. But in my output csv file, some of my points are left out. In the original datasets, none of these points (in the input or target sets...) seem to have anything different with them. And Ive tried to run the tool several times, and it seems like its always the same points that are omitted. 
Anyone have a clue on what causes this problem?

My target file looks like this with the unique ID field being the first column.

```
776 20  21  Sommer  15  362090  6448220 91,17288005 81,29255262
777 20  21  Sommer  16  362080  6448220 82,0068365  89,23947222
778 20  21  Sommer  17  362070  6448220 72,84079294 93,09493861
779 20  21  Sommer  18  362060  6448220 63,67474938 87,23483922 
780 20  21  Sommer  19  362050  6448220 54,50154742 82,17765362 
781 20  21  Sommer  20  362040  6448220 45,32403426 77,6562944  
782 20  21  Sommer  21  362030  6448220 36,14652111 73,65212869
```

And my input file looks like this. The unique Id field is here the last column. 152 is one of the numbers that gets omitted (its supposed to link with 778 in the target set...)

```
Year    UTM-¿st UTM-nordID  Art     vei         turbin              unique ID field
2011    361452  6448500 20  Hjort   75,78870308 183,814654  H   175-200 149
2011    361322  6448500 20  Hjort   30,24121334 88,0259451  D   75-100  150
2011    362043  6448230 25  Hjort   70,09615368 533,61694   NA  >200    151
2011    362070  6448220 25  Hjort   93,09493861 560,4653704 NA  >200    152
2011    362152  6448220 25  Hjort   40,42562935 624,70644   NA  >200    153
2011    362177  6448220 25  Hjort   31,05429277 645,0934399 NA  >200    154
2011    362191  6448219 25  Hjort   27,17585338 657,2094756 NA  >200    155
2011    362194  6448218 25  Hjort   26,84745014 660,2549379 NA  >200    156
2011    362208  6448219 25  Hjort   20,19118365 671,3551471 NA  >200    157
```

The datasets consists of approx 1200 and 650 rows.

I also tried stripping down the input and target file to the bare necessities, the coordinates and Id columns, but the same rows will be left out..

Comment: I also tried stripping down the input and target datasets to the bare necessities, but still the same rows are omitted...

Comment: Please do not comment on your own question. All details should be placed in the question itself by using the **edit** button. It would probably help to specify that you are using QGIS in the question body, along with the version and platform.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to the original question, and will therefore answer it here, and make a new question.

Turns out that the points that are omitted are the ones that match exactly , or that has 0 metres between them.

New question will be about how I can make a distance matrix with both the nearest points with distance >1 m and the ones that match exactly.

[New question here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/179165/qgis-distance-matrix-tool-how-to-include-distances-at-0-metres)